# Faraday’s Law and voltage balance

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, electromagnetic, winding, faradays-law

Does anyone know how to use Faraday’s Law and voltage balance to explain this equation?

I don't understand where jw comes from.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't know where this equation comes from, and you haven't defined the term \$\rho\$. But \$j\omega\$ usually shows up when we convert differential equations to frequency domain and the time derivative turns into \$j\omega\$.

Comment: I think I know how to get this, thanks.